# dev_appserver.py doesn't find my app.yaml

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I've updated gcloud and now this command

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml --port 9000
```

returns

```
No such file or directory: 'app.yaml'
```

I'm in my project directory, before it worked just fine. Now I need to specify the full path to app.yaml file

```
gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 219.0.1
app-engine-python 1.9.76
bq 2.0.34
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.0.2
core 2018.09.28
gsutil 4.34
```